# model in knockout trying to map again every time the ajax request returns. view is not updated

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I started using knockout in my asp.net mvc 2 project

anyway i tried something simple. 
i created a model like so:

```
var userViewModel = {
ID: ko.observable(),
assignedGroups: ko.observableArray(),
avilableGroups: ko.observableArray(),
permissions: ko.observableArray()
};
```

then on the document.ready of jquery i called:

```
ko.applyBindings(userViewModel);
```

in the aspx itself i have:

```
<select multiple id="groupOfUser" class="multi_added_groups" data-bind="foreach:    assignedGroups">
  <option data-bind="text: $data, value: $data"></option>
</select> 
<span data-bind="text: ID"></span>
```

if i first put data into userViewModel 
the view displays as expected. and that's great
but i want the view to start off empty at first.
then after the user chooses a user i make an ajax request 
my response is this:

```
{"ID":691,
"assignedGroups":["group1","group2"],
"avilableGroups":["role.administrator","role.editor"],
"permissions":[{"name":"admin","level":"ReadWrite"},
{"name":"admin.errorInfo","level":"Read"}]
 }
```

then in my callback function:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(res, userViewModel);
```

and that's it i guess. my view doesn't get refreshed with the new data from the server...
what am i doing wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this issue myself a couple of times. It seems that the mapping plugin expects your object to have been initially created from mapped data. This is a bit of a limitation of the plugin but can easily be worked around. Here is an example of creating your properties with the plugin where the update works correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/8BVMZ/1/

```
var userViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS({
        ID: "",
        assignedGroups: [],
        avilableGroups: [],
        permissions: []            
    }, {}, self);

    userSelected = function () {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(ajaxResponse, {}, self);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self)));
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.